# How to Auto Populate the next row in a table in Excel with Sequential data

Tags: excel

I've been tasked with creating a table with validations for different departments/people and need as little errors as possible whenever data is typed into the table by the various people who will be using it.

One of the columns I have is for a Control # which I need to be automatically added with a sequential number related to the previous row whenever a new row is created since it's not something that should be altered.

For example, Control # `X27906` on Row 1 will need to be auto populated with `X27907` for row 2, `X27908` for Row 3 and so on but I'm not entirely certain on how to do this since each time I add a new table I have to type in the new control number.

I've added a picture for reference.

I'm using Excel 2013.

[image: Control # Table Example]

Comment: is the letter prefix always one character?

Comment: Yes, it's always an X with 5 numerical characters following

Comment: `="X"&RIGHT(B2,5)+1` where B2 is the cell with `X27906` is in your example  the formula would be placed in the cell directly under that

Comment: That worked. Thank you!